# Search for ASCII values in sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table that one of the fields needs to be cleaned up. The basic table structure is as follows:

```
create table testComments(id int, comments text)
```

In the comments column some of the rows had to many "carriage returns" (char(13)) and "line feed" (char(10)). If there is more then one grouping per line I need to be able to modify it. The basic select statement that I have so far is a follows:

```
  select count(id)
  from testComments
  where comments like('%' +  char(13) + char(10) + char(13) + char(10) + '%')
```

This query will find the results

```
"This is a entry in the testComments crlf
crlf
In the comments field that works"
```

Although the query will not find the results if the comment is listed as follows:

```
"This is an entry in the testComments crlf
crlf
crlf
That will not work"
```

The query will only return a count of 1 entry for the above data. Any idea how I can change the query to return a count of 2?

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean return a count of 2?  You just need logic to pick up the latter example, right?

Comment: Yes Goat CO I just need the logic to pick up the latter example.

Comment: That query should return each of those texts. Are you sure there isn't something else wrong? Maybe the second text contains only `Char(10)` (lf).

Comment: To illustrate @GolezTrol's point, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b0ea/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code you gave us, your query should work properly.  So the details appear to be different, and I suspect that GolezTrol's comment is on the right track -- some of the CRLF pairs are really just solo CR or LF characters.

Try this:

```
select count(id)
  from #testComments
  where comments like('%' +  char(13) + char(10) + char(13) + char(10) + '%')
     or comments like('%' +  char(10) + char(10) + '%')
     or comments like('%' +  char(13) + char(13) + '%')
```

Comment: This is correct, I knew it was something simple like this. I just couldn't figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*The query will only return a count of 1 entry for the above data. Any idea how I can change the query to return a count of 2?*

I think you're misunderstanding something basic.
The COUNT-Function returns the count of all returned rows. In your example it is still returning **one** row.

So no matter if you have this:

```
"This is an entry in the testComments crlf
crlf
That will not work"
```

Or this:

```
"This is an entry in the testComments crlf
crlf
crlf
crlf
crlf
That will not work"
```

**COUNT will still return 1!** (If you have one record that has this string)

**EDIT:** If you literally want to count the characters for each row, here you go:

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(myColumn, 'yourCharacter', '')) FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a virtual table. I added up the differences in length of the comments field and the comments field after replacing the characters that you are looking for with empty strings.

```
SELECT SUM(DIF) FROM (
select    
(
  LEN(comments)
          - LEN( REPLACE(   REPLACE ( comments, char(13), ''),char(10),'') ) 
) 
 AS DIF    
 from #testComments
 ) as VT;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he doesn't want to simply detect strings with a CR or LF, but rather detect string with a pair of CRLF next to each other with nothing between them. (i.e he's looking for blank lines)

Comment: Then he will simply have to swap char(13) / char(10) with the character(s) of interest. At the very least, this should be enough to get started.

Comment: Wasn't that the reason for his question?  Without answering that, how have you helped?

Comment: I will be more concrete with my answers going forward.